# CSS button floating issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an UL with tabs (LI) and count of tabs may be different depending on user roles.
I want to place a button at the end of my UL and want it always to be right align.

[image]

But it is not right align in sum, although it has right align property.
[image]

Maybe someone can provide any solution?

```
                        <ul id="menu">
                        <li id="homeOption">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {

                             if (User.IsInRole("Role1"))
                             {
                                 <li id="agencyImportOption">@Html.ActionLink("link1")</li>
                             }

                               if (User.IsInRole("Role2"))
                             {
                                 <li id="agencyImportOption">@Html.ActionLink("link2")</li>
                             }

                             if (User.IsInRole("Role3"))
                             {
                                 <li id="agencyImportOption">@Html.ActionLink("link3")</li>
                             }

                        <li id="aboutOption">@Html.ActionLink("About")</li>
                        <li>
                        <button class="testButton" style="float:right; margint-right: 0px;">test button<button></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Pictures are nice, but you'll need to post your code.

Comment: no code = no help :/

Comment: Add float:right; to the last li :)

Comment: Why do you add button in a ul list? You add the button inside the li tag

Comment: Bojan Petkovski, I tried, unfortunately, does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/mmqxgony/

The html

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="homeOption">Home</li>
    <li id="agencyImportOption">link1</li>
    <li id="aboutOption">About</li>
    <li class="last">
        <button class="testButton" style="float:right; margint-right: 0px;">test button</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css

```
#menu{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
#menu li.last{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Add `overflow: auto` to `#menu` to constrain the floats to within the edges of the parent block, otherwise, this is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is HTML.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="homeOption">Home</li>
    <li id="agencyImportOption">link1</li>
    <li id="aboutOption">About</li>
    <li>
    <button class="testButton" style="float:right; margint-right: 0px;">test button</button>
</li>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
   list-style: outside none none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;/* if you need*/
}
#menu > li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu > li:last-child{
  float: right;
}
```